# PHP IMAP header caching

Tags: php, caching, imap, email-headers

I'm writing some fairly unremarkable php code to retrieve email via `IMAP` from a high load server.

My pseudo-code so far:

```
imap_open(..)
get_message_ids(..)
foreach message_id {
   $header_info = imap_headerinfo(..)
   $header = imap_fetchheader(..)  // I need full headers
   $structure = imap_fetchstructure(..)
   foreach($structure->parts as $part)
      get_part();
}
```

`imap_headerinfo()`, `imap_fetchheader()` and `imap_fetchstructure()` all parse the email header.

Is the email header downloaded separately each time or is it cached?

If there is no caching, I'd rather just download the raw header once with `imap_fetchheader()` and parse it with user code.

Comment: it will be downloaded each time the function is called

Comment: You'd rather write an email parser? Fun. Start with parsing the Date field. Just a chore in theory, but it'll take you a few days to handle the common syntax errors. Then you can decide whether to handle the uncommon ones.

Comment: I'm was just going to use imap_rfc822_parse_headers() unless you know of any issues with it.